# Debian 10で`make build`を実行しますと`WARNING Compiled with 2 warnings`と出ます。

Tags: linux, bash, debian

おはようございます。お世話になります。

ActivityWatchというManicTimeと同等の機能のOSSをDebian 10にインストールしようとしておりますが、`make build`を実行しますと下記のメッセージが出てきました。

```sh
省略
Images and other types of assets omitted.

 DONE  Build complete. The dist directory is ready to be deployed.
 INFO  Check out deployment instructions at https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html

make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-server/aw-webui'
cp -r aw-webui/dist/* aw_server/static/
rm -rf aw-webui/node_modules/.cache  # Needed for https://github.com/ActivityWatch/activitywatch/pull/274, works around https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/6279
pip3 install . -r requirements.txt
Processing /home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-server
Requirement already satisfied: aniso8601==8.0.0 in /home/yusuke/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 2)) (8.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: appdirs==1.4.3 in /home/yusuke/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 3)) (1.4.3)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs==19.3.0 in /home/yusuke/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 4)) (19.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: click==7.0 in /home/yusuke/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 5)) (7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: flask-cors==3.0.8 in /home/yusuke/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 6)) (3.0.8)
Requirement already satisfied: flask-restplus==0.13.0 in /home/yusuke/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 7)) (0.13.0)
Requirement already satisfied: flask==1.1.1 in /home/yusuke/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 8)) (1.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: aw-core from git+https://github.com/ActivityWatch/aw-core.git@ef604753fed1aa972ab211314779c042d8180b64#egg=aw-core in /home/yusuke/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 9)) (0.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: importlib-metadata==0.23 in /home/yusuke/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 10)) (0.23)
Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous==1.1.0 in /home/yusuke/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 11)) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: jinja2==2.10.3 in /home/yusuke/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 12)) (2.10.3)
Requirement already satisfied: jsonschema==3.1.1 in /home/yusuke/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 13)) (3.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: markupsafe==1.1.1 in /home/yusuke/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 14)) (1.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: more-itertools==7.2.0 in /home/yusuke/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 15)) (7.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyrsistent==0.15.5 in /home/yusuke/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 16)) (0.15.5)
Requirement already satisfied: python-json-logger==0.1.11 in /home/yusuke/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 17)) (0.1.11)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz==2019.3 in /home/yusuke/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 18)) (2019.3)
Requirement already satisfied: six==1.13.0 in /home/yusuke/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 19)) (1.13.0)
Requirement already satisfied: werkzeug==0.16.0 in /home/yusuke/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 20)) (0.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: zipp==0.6.0 in /home/yusuke/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 21)) (0.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: strict-rfc3339==0.7 in /home/yusuke/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from aw-core->-r requirements.txt (line 9)) (0.7)
Requirement already satisfied: peewee==3.11.2 in /home/yusuke/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from aw-core->-r requirements.txt (line 9)) (3.11.2)
Requirement already satisfied: iso8601==0.1.12 in /home/yusuke/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from aw-core->-r requirements.txt (line 9)) (0.1.12)
Requirement already satisfied: takethetime==0.3.1 in /home/yusuke/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from aw-core->-r requirements.txt (line 9)) (0.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from jsonschema==3.1.1->-r requirements.txt (line 13)) (40.8.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: aw-server
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for aw-server ... done
  Stored in directory: /home/yusuke/.cache/pip/wheels/ac/70/65/307cb1a325c39e099640dfb2db0354f6cab057f1c33113dff5
Successfully built aw-server
Installing collected packages: aw-server
  Found existing installation: aw-server 0.8.dev0+c6433ea
    Uninstalling aw-server-0.8.dev0+c6433ea:
      Successfully uninstalled aw-server-0.8.dev0+c6433ea
  The script aw-server is installed in '/home/yusuke/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.                                 
Successfully installed aw-server-0.8.dev0+c6433ea
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-server'
make --directory=aw-watcher-afk build DEV=
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-watcher-afk'
pip3 install . -r requirements.txt
Ignoring pyobjc-framework-Quartz: markers 'sys_platform == "darwin"' don't match your environment
Processing /home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-watcher-afk
Requirement already satisfied: aw-core from git+https://github.com/ActivityWatch/aw-core.git@master#egg=aw-core in /home/yusuke/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 1)) (0.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: aw-client from git+https://github.com/ActivityWatch/aw-client.git@master#egg=aw-client in /home/yusuke/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 2)) (0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: python-xlib from git+https://github.com/python-xlib/python-xlib.git@master#egg=python-xlib in /home/yusuke/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 5)) (0.25)
Requirement already satisfied: pyuserinput from git+https://github.com/PyUserInput/PyUserInput.git@ac2d4c7a7f4b1a72e70b1a2ef8925d5312fb12bc#egg=pyuserinput in /home/yusuke/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 6)) (0.1.12)
Requirement already satisfied: six==1.13.0 in /home/yusuke/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from aw-core->-r requirements.txt (line 1)) (1.13.0)
Requirement already satisfied: jsonschema==3.1.1 in /home/yusuke/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from aw-core->-r requirements.txt (line 1)) (3.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: peewee==3.11.2 in /home/yusuke/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from aw-core->-r requirements.txt (line 1)) (3.11.2)
Requirement already satisfied: importlib-metadata==0.23 in /home/yusuke/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from aw-core->-r requirements.txt (line 1)) (0.23)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs==19.3.0 in /home/yusuke/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from aw-core->-r requirements.txt (line 1)) (19.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: appdirs==1.4.3 in /home/yusuke/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from aw-core->-r requirements.txt (line 1)) (1.4.3)
Requirement already satisfied: python-json-logger==0.1.11 in /home/yusuke/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from aw-core->-r requirements.txt (line 1)) (0.1.11)
Requirement already satisfied: pyrsistent==0.15.5 in /home/yusuke/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from aw-core->-r requirements.txt (line 1)) (0.15.5)
Requirement already satisfied: strict-rfc3339==0.7 in /home/yusuke/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from aw-core->-r requirements.txt (line 1)) (0.7)
Requirement already satisfied: zipp==0.6.0 in /home/yusuke/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from aw-core->-r requirements.txt (line 1)) (0.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: more-itertools==7.2.0 in /home/yusuke/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from aw-core->-r requirements.txt (line 1)) (7.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: iso8601==0.1.12 in /home/yusuke/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from aw-core->-r requirements.txt (line 1)) (0.1.12)
Requirement already satisfied: takethetime==0.3.1 in /home/yusuke/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from aw-core->-r requirements.txt (line 1)) (0.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: persist-queue in /home/yusuke/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from aw-client->-r requirements.txt (line 2)) (0.3.5)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from aw-client->-r requirements.txt (line 2)) (2.21.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from jsonschema==3.1.1->aw-core->-r requirements.txt (line 1)) (40.8.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: aw-watcher-afk
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for aw-watcher-afk ... done
  Stored in directory: /home/yusuke/.cache/pip/wheels/c8/07/87/d1071a2e48fee0885f193552e115f2d5eba9e93cfa0ac95fe7
Successfully built aw-watcher-afk
Installing collected packages: aw-watcher-afk
  Found existing installation: aw-watcher-afk 0.2
    Uninstalling aw-watcher-afk-0.2:
      Successfully uninstalled aw-watcher-afk-0.2
  The script aw-watcher-afk is installed in '/home/yusuke/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.                                 
Successfully installed aw-watcher-afk-0.2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-watcher-afk'
make --directory=aw-watcher-window build DEV=
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-watcher-window'
pip3 install . -r requirements.txt
Ignoring wmi: markers 'sys_platform == "win32"' don't match your environment
Ignoring pypiwin32: markers 'sys_platform == "win32"' don't match your environment
Processing /home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-watcher-window
Requirement already satisfied: aw-core from git+https://github.com/ActivityWatch/aw-core.git@master#egg=aw-core in /home/yusuke/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 1)) (0.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: aw-client from git+https://github.com/ActivityWatch/aw-client.git@master#egg=aw-client in /home/yusuke/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 2)) (0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: python-xlib in /home/yusuke/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 6)) (0.25)
Requirement already satisfied: pyrsistent==0.15.5 in /home/yusuke/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from aw-core->-r requirements.txt (line 1)) (0.15.5)
Requirement already satisfied: takethetime==0.3.1 in /home/yusuke/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from aw-core->-r requirements.txt (line 1)) (0.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: iso8601==0.1.12 in /home/yusuke/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from aw-core->-r requirements.txt (line 1)) (0.1.12)
Requirement already satisfied: strict-rfc3339==0.7 in /home/yusuke/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from aw-core->-r requirements.txt (line 1)) (0.7)
Requirement already satisfied: jsonschema==3.1.1 in /home/yusuke/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from aw-core->-r requirements.txt (line 1)) (3.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: more-itertools==7.2.0 in /home/yusuke/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from aw-core->-r requirements.txt (line 1)) (7.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: peewee==3.11.2 in /home/yusuke/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from aw-core->-r requirements.txt (line 1)) (3.11.2)
Requirement already satisfied: zipp==0.6.0 in /home/yusuke/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from aw-core->-r requirements.txt (line 1)) (0.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: python-json-logger==0.1.11 in /home/yusuke/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from aw-core->-r requirements.txt (line 1)) (0.1.11)
Requirement already satisfied: six==1.13.0 in /home/yusuke/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from aw-core->-r requirements.txt (line 1)) (1.13.0)
Requirement already satisfied: appdirs==1.4.3 in /home/yusuke/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from aw-core->-r requirements.txt (line 1)) (1.4.3)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs==19.3.0 in /home/yusuke/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from aw-core->-r requirements.txt (line 1)) (19.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: importlib-metadata==0.23 in /home/yusuke/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from aw-core->-r requirements.txt (line 1)) (0.23)
Requirement already satisfied: persist-queue in /home/yusuke/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from aw-client->-r requirements.txt (line 2)) (0.3.5)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from aw-client->-r requirements.txt (line 2)) (2.21.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from jsonschema==3.1.1->aw-core->-r requirements.txt (line 1)) (40.8.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: aw-watcher-window
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for aw-watcher-window ... done
  Stored in directory: /home/yusuke/.cache/pip/wheels/48/df/28/2ba39fe69caabc088eef815f7c1c669a10f4c0b2ffcf478b62
Successfully built aw-watcher-window
Installing collected packages: aw-watcher-window
  Found existing installation: aw-watcher-window 0.2
    Uninstalling aw-watcher-window-0.2:
      Successfully uninstalled aw-watcher-window-0.2
  The script aw-watcher-window is installed in '/home/yusuke/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.                                 
Successfully installed aw-watcher-window-0.2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-watcher-window'
make --directory=aw-qt build DEV=
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-qt'
pip3 install 'pyqt5<5.11'
Requirement already satisfied: pyqt5<5.11 in /home/yusuke/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (5.10.1)
Requirement already satisfied: sip<4.20,>=4.19.4 in /home/yusuke/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pyqt5<5.11) (4.19.8)
pyrcc5 -o aw_qt/resources.py aw_qt/resources.qrc
make[1]: pyrcc5: Command not found
make[1]: *** [Makefile:39: aw_qt/resources.py] Error 127
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-qt'
make: *** [Makefile:38: build] Error 2
```

そして、上記のメッセージの中にパスがどれかわからない、という内容のメッセージが出てきたのですが、下記のようにパスを通してもエラーメッセージが出てきます。

```
export PATH=$aw-server:/home/yusuke/.local/bin
export PATH=$aw-watcher-afk:/home/yusuke/.local/bin
export PATH=$aw-watcher-window:/home/yusuke/.local/bin
```

```
The script aw-server is installed in '/home/yusuke/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
```

```
The script aw-watcher-afk is installed in '/home/yusuke/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
```

```
  The script aw-watcher-window is installed in '/home/yusuke/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
```

どのようにすればエラーメッセージをなくせるのでしょうか。ご教授願ます。

Comment: `pyrcc5: Command not found` というエラーが出ていますので、`sudo apt install pyqt5-dev-tools` を試してみて下さい。

Comment: venv使ってますか？ドキュメントを見ると venv が推奨みたいですよ。 https://activitywatch.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing-from-source.html

Comment: そのPATHの通し方だと既存のPATHがすべて消えてしまっていませんか？

Comment: @metropolis 様　`sudo apt install pyqt5-dev-tools`をインストール致しました^_^

Comment: @take88 様 ご指摘感謝です。`venv`は`python3 -m venv venv`でインストール致しました。

Comment: @nekketsuuu 様 では、`export PATH=$PATH:/home/yusuke/.local/bin`みたいな感じで`/etc/bash.bashrc`に記述すればよろしいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PATH云々は警告なので 気にしなくてよいです。インストール先が `/home/yusuke/.local/bin` なので 必要に応じて、PATHに含めて使ってねと言うくらいのニュアンスだと思います。

ビルドエラーの内容は `pyrcc5: Command not found` です。

> pyrcc5 -o aw_qt/resources.py aw_qt/resources.qrc
>   make[1]: pyrcc5: Command not found

[ドキュメント](https://activitywatch.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing-from-source.html)の通りやると

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/ActivityWatch/activitywatch.git
cd activitywatch/
python3 -m venv venv
source ./venv/bin/activate
```

とすれば、./activitywatch/venv/bin/pyrcc5 があるので エラーを回避できる気がします。

Comment: 様 ご回答感謝です！エラーを回避できました！