# Debian 10の bashシェルですべてのコマンドが`command not found`と出るようになりました…。

Tags: linux, bash, debian

Debian 10の bashシェルですべてのコマンドが`command not found`と出るようになりました…。

どうすれば解決できるでしょうか。再インストールしかないのでしょうか。
ご教授願ます。

Comment: これ [いつものように本番作業してたはずなのに](https://qiita.com/2gt/items/d6906a185109e66df74f) と同様に`.profile`とか環境変数の`PATH`を書き換えてしまったのでは？

Comment: [別質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/61157/3060) でのexportが既存のPATHを上書きしてしまってますよね。

Comment: @kunif 様 ご教授いただき感謝です。

Comment: @cubick 様 ご教授いただき感謝です。

Answer (score 2):

質問者さんの[別の質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/61157/19110)において次のような操作をされていますが、これのせいで既存の PATH がすべて喪失していそうです。

```sh
export PATH=$aw-server:/home/yusuke/.local/bin
export PATH=$aw-watcher-afk:/home/yusuke/.local/bin
export PATH=$aw-watcher-window:/home/yusuke/.local/bin
```

つまり、既存の PATH を含めた形で `export PATH="/path/to/new/directory:$PATH"` のように書く必要があるところ、そうなっていないので PATH の内容がほとんど無くなってしまい、実行可能ファイルが見つからなくなってしまっています。

`~/.profile` 等の設定ファイルなどを特に上書きしていなければ、シェルを立ち上げ直せば復活するはずです。上書きしてしまった場合は、`/usr/bin/env -i /bin/bash --norc --noprofile` で既存の `.profile` 等を読み込まずに Bash を起動してその上で作業して設定ファイルを直すことができます。

Comment: 様 `env -i bash --norc --noprofile`をbashで実行したのですが、、`bash: env: command not found`としか出てきませんでした、、どうすれば`bash.bashrc`を読み込まずに起動できるのでしょうか？

Comment: 様 ご教授いただきありがとうございます。[別質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/61207/debian-10でbashを起動したときに-bash-dircolors-command-not-foundと出ます)に移行いたします。