# Debian 10でbashを起動したときに、bash: dircolors: command not foundと出ます。

Tags: linux, bash, debian

こんばんは。お世話になります。

Debian 10で`bash`を起動しました際に、`bash: dircolors: command not found`と出てすべてのコマンドを使えなくなり、`bash.bashrc`を書き換えることも不可能になってしまいました。

[別質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/61182/debian-10%E3%81%AE-bash%E3%82%B7%E3%82%A7%E3%83%AB%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%81%B9%E3%81%A6%E3%81%AE%E3%82%B3%E3%83%9E%E3%83%B3%E3%83%89%E3%81%8Ccommand-not-found%E3%81%A8%E5%87%BA%E3%82%8B%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8A%E3%81%BE%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F/61185#61185)でお尋ねした際に、「`~/.profile`等の設定ファイルなどを特に上書きしていなければ、シェルを立ち上げ直せば復活するはずです。上書きしてしまった場合は、`env -i bash --norc --noprofile`で既存の`.profile`等を読み込まずに`Bash`を起動してその上で作業して設定ファイルを直すことができます。」という内容をご教授いただきましたが、
`env -i bash --norc --noprofile`ですら実行できないのです…。

Debian 10での設定ファイルは`bash.bashrc`ですので、
`bash.bashrc`を起動せずにbashを動かす方法をご教授願います。

Comment: 絶対パスで指定するか、`/usr/bin/env -i /bin/bash --norc --noprofile` もしくは `source /etc/environment` として system の PATH 設定を使うのも良いかと。

Comment: @metropolis 様 PATH設定できました。ご教授いただきありがとうございます！

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(コメントより)

絶対パスで指定するか、`/usr/bin/env -i /bin/bash --norc --noprofile` もしくは `source /etc/environment` として system の PATH 設定を使うのも良いかと。